# Parameters in an ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use an ajax callback function twice.

I have two different arrays but quite the same, so the callback for both them is quite the same too, just the name of the array is changing. So I would like to call the same callback function for both arrays and give the name of the array in parameter of the callback, but I don't know how to do, I can't get the name.

So here is the ajax request and the function `insertTraitementCallback` called after.

```
$.post("ajaxUpdate.php", 
    { 
        arr: data_traitement, id_essai, table, idTable 
    },
        insertTraitementCallback, 'json'
);
```

And I declare my function like that :

```
function insertTraitementCallback(responseObject,ioArgs)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `responseObject` is the array you're referring to?

Comment: insertTraitementCallback need to take one arg and that's the json response.

Comment: @cr0ss No, `responseObject`and `ioArgs` are the default parameter, I just want to pass a string in parameter. So it will be 3 parameters in the function

Comment: I finally found. I just called an other function inside of the first one. Thanks ;)